# How to get a reference on the Itcl class member variable?

Tags: reference, tcl, incr-tcl

Say I have the following structure:

```
package require Itcl


itcl::class AAA {

private variable m_list {}

constructor {} {
    fill m_list list
}

}
```

How to get a reference on the m_list in order to write

```
foreach elem $reference {.......}
```

Consider that list is really big and I don't want to copy it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl variables use copy-on-write semantics. You can safely pass a value around, assigning multiple variables to it, without worrying about it taking up more space in memory.

For example

```
set x {some list} ;# there is one copy of the list, one variable pointing at it
set y $x          ;# there is one copy of the list, two variables pointing at it
set z $y          ;# there is one copy of the list, three variables pointing at it
lappend z 123     ;# there are two copies of the list
                  ;# x and y pointing at one
                  ;# z pointing at the other 
                  ;#     which is different from the first via an extra 123 at the end
```

The above code will result in two giant lists, one with the original data that both x any y point at, and one with the extra element of 123 that only z points to. Prior to the lappend statement, there was only one copy of the list and all three variables pointed at it.

Comment: Thanks, but is it right for itcl class member variables, particularly, lists?

Comment: The last time I checked, itcl member variables were the same as any other variable, they're a name for a value... and values themselves are copy on write.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get a reference on the member of a class:

```
package require Itcl


itcl::class AAA {

public variable m_var 5

public method getRef {} {

    return [itcl::scope m_var]
}

}


AAA a

puts [a cget -m_var]

set [a getRef] 10

puts [a cget -m_var]
```

Comment: Your answer describes how to get a "reference" to the member variable of an object so that, if you change it, it changes the value of the member variable in the class. In effect, an alias to the original value. While it will make sure you're not making another copy of the data when reading it, it's worth noting that just returning the value from a getter method will do the same thing. Ie, you answered his question with one way to not duplicate the data, but not the only way. (Just noting it)

Comment: I agree with you! Ther reference is for not-copying and also for modifying the referee, no? Then this should be the answer of my question I guess.

Comment: If you're looking to modify the original value, then this is the right answer. My answer assumes you're just looking to use it, not modify it.