# How to treat a return value from method as a class type - Itcl

Tags: class, tcl, return-value, itcl

Suppose I have the following code implemented in Itcl.

```
package require Itcl

itcl::class A {
    constructor {} { puts $this }
    destructor {}
    public method Print {} { puts "ok" }
}

itcl::class B {
    constructor {} { }
    destructor {}
    public method returnA {} { return [A #auto] }
}

B b   ;# create an instance of class B
set obj [b returnA]   ; #assign return value to obj
$obj Print    ;# should treat obj as an A type and print ok
```

Now, I get the following error:
invalid command name "0"
    while executing
"$obj Print"

I understood that I need to add scopes to my variable or to the Print command in order to invoke Print method that associated to class A.
But I don't really know how.

I also read the following post:

[How to get a reference on the Itcl class member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951626/how-to-get-a-reference-on-the-itcl-class-member-variable)

But it doesn't says there how to treat the return value as a specific class type variable

Comment: Allow for one question: Why are you training yourself on Itcl? Why not use `TclOO`, which is the built-in OO system, that comes with Tcl 8.6. Btw. newer ITcl versions are built on top of TclOO, so, there is little to gain, especially if get yourself started in Tcl (and you are not locked in to ITcl).

Comment: Also, the above snippet is not an MVE ... pls. pay more attention to this.

Comment: mrcalvin ,   
I need to provide an tcl - C++ API and I read that using Itcl is the best solution.   
Are you recommend to use TclOO instead? where can I read about it?

Comment: What is your source of information re: Itcl and C++? Best reach out to comp.lang.tcl to obtain feedback on technology choices regarding your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to qualify the name of the yet to be created instance of class `A`:

```
A [namespace current]::#auto
```

Otherwise, the name of the created object is returned in an unqualified manner (`0`, `a0`, ...), which cannot be resolved to a Tcl command for the scope of the caller of `returnA`.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/3zh3JOi3iWo